# <div> "circle" browser consistency, border-radius

Tags: javascript, html, css

As a test I tried making a `<div>` appear as a circle. The `<div>` has some text inside of it but otherwise is empty.

Then in JavaScript I calculate the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`, use the maximum of the two, and assign it to a variable named `diameter` (although realistically the width would probably always be larger). I use `diameter` to assign the `<div>` its width, height, and borderRadius. The result is something that looks like a circle (at least in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari. I have not tested IE).

Testing in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari I noticed that this behaves differently for CSS `hover` and JavaScript `onmousedown` when the cursor is just outside the area of the circle but inside the area of the rectangle that would be visible if `border-radius` was not set.

Here's the results when the cursor is in that spot:

- Chrome: `hover` and `onmousedown` affected outside the circle
- Firefox: `hover` and `onmousedown` only affected inside the circle
- Opera: `hover` and `onmousedown` affected outside the circle
- Safari: `hover` and `onmousedown` affected outside the circle

The behavior Firefox has is the one I'd like to consistently use, is there a way to make this possible?

**Edit**: If you find a solution please explain what browser you are using.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to illustrate your problem? My guess is that a property you are using is only being interpreted correctly by Firefox. Therefore, figuring what it is, you should have the same behavior in all browser.

Comment: The answer Hive7 gave below has a jsfiddle link that illustrates the problem. Adding `.circle:hover {background:#0f0;}` will show the `hover` problem.

Comment: On my end, this work as expected in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE9+ : http://jsfiddle.net/KLFLG/

Comment: Just looked at it (using Safari) and the area outside the circle where the rectangle would be if `border-radius` was not set makes the circle blue. Setting `width` and `height` to be larger makes the this more apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this issue is already fixed in Chrome 30 Canary. So the upcoming releases of Chrome and Opera (which has recently switched to Chrome's rendering engine) should behave the same way as Firefox. IE10 already behaves this way.

Comment: Basically this means that I cannot rely on it working for most people any time soon right?

Comment: No, I meant that the problem will soon go away and it will eventually work for most people. But I haven't found the workaround for existing stable releases of Chrome, Safari, and Opera, unfortunately.

Comment: The problem is that if I had made a site using this I would have been positioning the circles with JavaScript and the circles would be very close together. It seems that with the wrong browser behavior clicking in the problematic area could cause a confusion on which circle was clicked.

Comment: Yes, for very close circles this can happen. Probably it would be better to use SVG or old-school image maps with <area shape="circle"> instead for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using css hacks so that you can set specific css types depending on the Browser that the user is using. Here is a site that gives an explanation:

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

If not here is a fiddle of a circle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rPtAV/6/

Here is the css that I used:

```
.circle {
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 20000px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That is an exhaustive CSS selection and I am not sure how to overcome Chrome / Opera / Safari using it. The example in the jsfiddle link has the same problem I described, try adding `.circle:hover {background:#0f0;}` to see it.

Comment: the border radius can be used in different browser as -webkit-border-radius for chrome and safari, -moz-border-radius for firefox, and give value to border-radius:100%

Comment: I still see the same problem in Chrome, Opera, and Safari. Hive7, what browser are you looking at it in? I tried adding to your jsfiddle as well, no effect on the behavior though: http://jsfiddle.net/rPtAV/9/