# CSS Circle behavior when click or hover

Tags: css

I have a circle:

HTML:

```
<div id="quadrant-sizer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#quadrant-sizer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 999px;
}
```

My issue is that when I have the mouse outside of the circle, but still within the hight and width of the box, it will behave as if it is on the circle. Basically, if the mouse is not on the circle, it shouldn't act as if it is. If not possible with HTML/CSS, is there a way to do it in JavaScript?

[My example](http://jsfiddle.net/rayholland/zSRXU/4/)

[Easier to visualize example](http://davidwalsh.name/css-circles)

Comment: What browser(s) are you seeing this in? It seems like a bug. For example, in Chrome 28 this works correctly...

Comment: Chrome 28, look at the second example, when you hover just to the bottom right of the yellow circle the mouse behavior will change.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388607/div-circle-browser-consistency-border-radius/

Answer (score 3):

What if you change the CSS-rule to:

```
#quadrant-sizer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%; /* here */
}
```

**Update:**

In any case it is most likely a browser/version issue. It seem to work with Canary 30, but not Chrome 27 and 28. Works with Aurora 24.

Comment: The second example does that and it still has the wrong behavior

Comment: @Raymond it is most likely a browser/version issue. It seem to work with Canary 30, but not Chrome 27 and 28. Works with Aurora 24.

Comment: how is that solving the problem? It doesn't matter if it's px or %.

Comment: @Christoph it doesn't. It was part of the first response (and is in any case correct way to make a circle). The bottom text was added later (see edit history and updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with javascript is basically finding out whether the mouse is in the cirle or not. Use [THIS FORMULA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle)  [image] for calculating it.

Answer (score 1):

Current browsers seem to have some inconsistency in handling rounded corners in this way, but the situation [tends to get improved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393234/2533215).

The HTML's native way to create a circular active area is using `<map>` with `<area shape="circle">`. But JS still will be needed to visualize interactions other than just opening a link.